# Nginx is redirecting to subdomain after changes to ssl https

Tags: wordpress, ssl, nginx

I am on AWS Ubuntu server and had my domain verified and a certificate from certificate manager, but I couldn't manage to use it on my server, seems like it is for external traffic.  Anyhow, I went with a letsencrypt guide from https://hackernoon.com/easy-lets-encrypt-certificates-on-aws-79387767830b

and then went into my etc/nginx/sites-available and edited mysite.com's virtual server file.  The settings are below.  I have two subdomains, asdf.mysite.com asdf2.mysite.com and the main one has wordpress.  Now, the main site redirects to the first subdomain asdf.mysite.com.  How do I get https on my nginx server and have it direct to the main site?

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/chain.pem;
    server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;
    root /var/www/wordpress;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    client_max_body_size 100M;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300s;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "upload_max_filesize = 50M \n post_max_size=51M";
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300s;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300s;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't "redirects" to your first subdomain. Looks like this subdomain becomes the default server listening on plain HTTP port 80 after you changed your configuration for this one. Read [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) article for details if you're interested. If you explicily type `https://www.yourdomain.com` in the browser address bar, I think you'll get your site back. You need to add another `server` block to this configuration file that will do HTTP to HTTPS redirection for your main site:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, simple thing like that fixed it!  I knew it had something to do with return because I saw it in other guides, but when I put it in it didn't work, probably because it didn't have the https:// after the return 301.  Huge help, thanks again!